# Splitting an audio signal into multiple audio signals based on frequency range in Librosa

Tags: python, source-separation

Using the Librosa package in Python, how may I separate an audio signal into multiple audio signals based on frequency range?

I have a file `music.mp3`. I used HPSS to separate the music's harmonic and percussive components, which I was able to do with [librosa.effects.hpss()](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.effects.hpss.html). This was done so I can use the percussive component for a more reliable beat detection using [Librosa's beat tracker](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.beat.beat_track.html).

However, I'd like to further separate the harmonic component of `music.mp3` into two more separate signals `bass.mp3`, `midrange.mp3` where:

- `bass.mp3` contains the 20-250 Hz frequencies of the harmonic component,
- `midrange.mp3` contains the 251-4000 Hz frequencies of the harmonic component.

I plan on doing this because when constructing a [chromagram](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.chroma_cqt.html) out of the harmonic component, it only gives me the twelve pitch classes for that component, where it coalesces all frequencies of the same pitch class (e.g. C2, C3, C4) into one bin (C). By separating the harmonic component further, I am able to get more divisions.

But how do I do this with Librosa?

Comment: How about a simple bandpass filter prior to the chromagram?  Would that not work?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am looking to do something similar for a different purpose?